# Exporting an image is no longer possible

Tags: excel

Since the conversion to Excel 2016 the code does not work anymore. As soon as I do that, I just get a whiteimage with the dimensions of the right image. Has anyone an idea of the reasons why?

```
Sub BildExportShape(shExport As Shape)
    Dim chDiagramm As ChartObject
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    shExport.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set chDiagramm = Tabelle2.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, shExport.Width, shExport.Height)
    With chDiagramm.Chart
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="H:\Signatur\Wappen.jpg", FilterName:="JPG" ' andere Grafikformate sind möglich
    End With
    chDiagramm.Delete
    Set chDiagramm = Nothing
    Set shExport = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try activating the chart before you paste and export it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no other result.

Comment: I'd also recommend clearing the chartarea before you paste anything. Other than that, I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It is not a diagram, its a picture what he exports from the table

Answer (score 0):

Try without disabling the screen updating, I believe it was giving me problems so I had to do that without disabling.

```
            Call AhorroMemoria(False)
            Imagen.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
            With wsM.ChartObjects.Add(Imagen.Left - Imagen.Left * 0.15, Imagen.Top - Imagen.Top * 0.15, _
                Imagen.Width - Imagen.Width * 0.15, Imagen.Height - Imagen.Height * 0.15)
                .Activate
                wsM.Shapes("Gráfico 1").Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .Chart.Paste
                .Chart.Export wb.Path & "\" & Servicio & Contador & ".jpg", "JPG"
            End With
            Call AhorroMemoria(True)
```

This is my function AhorroMemoria:

```
Sub AhorroMemoria(isOn As Boolean)

    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub
```